# "Converting Address to Address Payable - Need Assistance"

Tags: addresses, payable, address.transfer

[image]

below is my code :

```
function withdraw() external isOwner() {
        address payable owner = address(uint160(getOwner()));
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
```

what is wrong in the address conversion error, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [solidity 0.6](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/types.html#address), you can cast `address` to `address payable` via

```
address addr = 0x****;
address payable wallet = payable(addr);
```

..so, in this case, try the following edit:

```
function withdraw() external isOwner() {
        address payable owner = payable(getOwner());
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
```

**NotaBene**

I’m unsure as to wether or not this will successfully compile since you haven’t shared your code for the function call `isOwner'()` - it seems odd to call a function in declaring a function. Each to his own, of course, I’m just unsure if this will successfully compile

Comment: The way i understand it is that isOwner is just a modifier (the parenthesis are optionnal when the modifier don't take in any arguments, but leaving them in is still correct syntax). I'm more wierded out by the wierd type conversion done when calling getOwner(). Why is  it being converted to an uint160 first? Was that a blind attempt to fix the error, or does getOwner returns an uint256 or something like that? If that's the case they'd have to do `payable(address(uint160(getOwner());`

Comment: I have taken the logic based on in the below document- https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#address

Comment: That’s an interesting thought. I’d suppose of you still got a Implicit Conversion error after the above edit (since we don’t have the code here for getOwner()) , that would be the next bet